# Python 3 - Return dictionary key of searched value

Tags: python

I'm wanting to return the key of a list within a dictionary, if the searched value is contained within that list. I can't seem to figure it out, the closest I have got is to search the key and return the list :/

Here's my code

```
mylist =   {'Bob':['Harry','Jenkins', 'Onion', 'Fred', 'Earl', 'Sam'],
            'Wayne':['Wallace', 'David', 'Eel', 'Perkins', 'Fruit', 'Angela'],
            'Jeff':['Aaron', 'Cameron', 'Keith', 'Winston', 'Geoff', 'Wayne']
            }


def tester(name):
     if name in mylist:
        print (True)
        print(mylist.get(name))
```

So if I search the dictionary for 'Jenkins' it should return 'Bob'

Comment: what happens if multiple lists contain that item?

Comment: For what i'm doing they won't, each list will have unique names

Comment: It sounds that you arranged the data the wrong way around. It looks like `'Jenkins'` is associated with one name `'Bob'`, but not the other way around. That sounds like you should have `'Bob'` as key and `'Jenkins'` as value instead. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Not sure why this is marked as duplicate but I think I have a better solution than using the existing one. Since we are iterating the whole dictionary for each query, why don't we iterate the dictionary just once and create a new dictionary which is the reverse of the original with the keys being each element in the list mapped to keys in the original list. This will reduce time for each query. Let me know if I am wrong somewhere. Here is the code
https://gist.github.com/kaushik94/d8378372b06cf18bff5a

Comment: @kaushik94 Depends on the real use case. It's a computation vs. memory  and complexity tradeoff. For a tiny array it's not worth the additional complexity. For large arrays, time critical code or often-repeated code restructuring the data becomes interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
next((key for key, names in mylist.items() if 'Fred' in names), None)
```

This will return `'Bob'`. Substitute `'Fred'` by your variable to search for. Returns `None` if the name is not found.

Comment: Awesome Thanks @deceze !

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over **`dictionary items`** see if the current list contains the search value if so return the key else return "No"

**Code:**

```
mylist =   {'Bob':['Harry','Jenkins', 'Onion', 'Fred', 'Earl', 'Sam'],
            'Wayne':['Wallace', 'David', 'Eel', 'Perkins', 'Fruit', 'Angela'],
            'Jeff':['Aaron', 'Cameron', 'Keith', 'Winston', 'Geoff', 'Wayne']
            }

def tester(name):
    for keys,value in mylist.items():
        if name in value:
            return keys
    return None

print(tester("Harry"))
```

**Output:**

```
Bob
```

Comment: Returning `"No"` looks like a bad idea. What if you have mr No among the names? You should probably either return a distinguished value (such as `None`) or raise exception to indicate the name wasn't found.

Comment: I get this error, are there any equivalent functions that work with Python 3?

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Jordan/Desktop/answer.py", line 12, in <module>
    print (tester("Harry"))
  File "/Users/Jordan/Desktop/answer.py", line 7, in tester
    for keys,value in mylist.iteritems():
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'

Comment: @skyking in that case None would be the best I think so

Comment: @greystash see the edit

Comment: @greystash happy to help

Comment: @VigneshKalai It still isn't allowed in python3 as there no longer exist a `print` statement.